# How to drop pandas dataframe rows based on conditions that consider other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df

```
df

      time                       entry

0   2022-07-28 13:35:00         True
1   2022-07-29 14:15:00         True
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The "entry" inside df IS ALWAYS True

sample code to generate it:

```
import pandas as pd

tbl = {"time" :["2022-07-28 13:35:00", "2022-07-29 14:15:00"],
      "entry" : [True, True]}

df = pd.DataFrame(tbl)
```

I have another dataframe that starts from the df time, but it has more dates, we will call this, df2:

```
df2


time                      entry      target_long      stop_long

0   2022-07-28 13:35:00       True          NaN             NaN
1   2022-07-28 13:35:15       True          NaN             NaN
2   2022-07-28 13:35:30       NaN           NaN             True
3   2022-07-28 13:35:45       True          NaN             NaN
.          . 
.          .
n    2022-07-29 14:15:00      True          NaN             NaN
n+1  2022-07-29 14:15:15      True          NaN             NaN
n+2  2022-07-29 14:15:30      True          NaN             NaN
n+3  2022-07-29 14:15:45      NaN           True            NaN
n+4  2022-07-29 14:16:00      True          NaN             NaN
n+5  2022-07-29 14:16:15      NaN           True            NaN
```

sample code to generate it:

```
tbl2 = {"time" :["2022-07-28 13:35:00", "2022-07-28 13:35:15", "2022-07-28 13:35:30",
            "2022-07-28 13:35:45", "2022-07-29 14:15:00","2022-07-29 14:15:15",
            "2022-07-29 14:15:30", "2022-07-29 14:15:45", "2022-07-29 14:16:00", 
            "2022-07-29 14:16:15"],
    "entry" : [True, True, "NaN", True, True, True, True, "NaN", True, "NaN"],
   "target_long" : ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", True, "NaN", True],
    "stop_long" : ["NaN", "NaN", True, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN"]}

 df2 = pd.DataFrame(tbl2)
```

I need that when the "entry" in df2 is NaN AND if (("stop_long" is True) OR (target_long is True)), drop all other lines of df2, BUT if the time of df2 is inside df, so DON'T drop, but start to do the same thing of before.

The result will be a dataframe that will look like this:

```
df3

   time                        entry      target_long      stop_long

0   2022-07-28 13:35:00       True          NaN             NaN
1   2022-07-28 13:35:30       NaN           NaN             True

2   2022-07-29 14:15:00       True          NaN              NaN
3   2022-07-29 14:15:45       NaN           True             NaN
```

I tried this method, it works considering sample code, but it gives me problems in my real code:

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df2.time = pd.to_datetime(df2.time)

df = df.set_index('time')
df2 = df2.set_index('time')

df = df.replace('NaN', False).astype(bool)
df2 = df2.replace('NaN', False).astype(bool)

df3 = (df2.groupby(df2.index.date)
         .apply(lambda x: x[~x.entry & (x.target_long | x.stop_long) | x.index.isin(df.index)]
            [lambda y: y[(y.index <= y.target_long.idxmax()) | (y.index <= 
       y.stop_long.idxmax())]])
      .droplevel(-2)
      .dropna(how='all')
      .reset_index())
print(df3)
```

In my real code, this method gives me this df3:

[image: df3]

So the problem is the multiple "True" values inside stop_long column and target_long column, It should be only one "True" per date considered inside df

NB: The date inside my real df2 is not the same as in sample code, but that's ok, I provided a sample code as simple as possible.

Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too complex to understand.
Try to make it simpler.

Generally in such cases the best way is to merge the two DFs and then use multiple criteria filtering. e.g.

```
df = df2.merge(right = df, on='time', how = 'left')
df = df[(df['stop_long'] == True) & (df['target_long'] == True)]
```

Comment: thanks. can you provide please working code that can be tested in the sample code i provided?

Comment: For that I need to understand better what you are trying to do. I could not understand from the description above